redis-cli json key regex match
I am fairly new to redis. Started using redis with ':' separated namespaces to store pickle data.
It's easier to search for what data is stored using wildcard searches on redis clients(redisinsights for example).
e.g. If data is stored in a hierarchal structure
key=source1:20240506:part1:subtype1:1   value=pickle(dataset1)
key=source1:20240506:part2:subtype2:2   value=pickle(dataset2)
A scan on the client for example source1:202405* shows a list of keys that can be then individually explored.
The question now is, why isn't wildcard search on key/namespace supported if i use json.set instead ?
Whenever i tried a wildcard scan, no data is shown. However, data is shown if i use an exact key.

Works on my machine:
127.0.0.1:6379> json.set source1:20240506:part1:subtype1:1 $ '{ "foo": "bar" }'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> json.set source1:20240506:part1:subtype1:2 $ '{ "baz": "qux" }'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 MATCH source1:202405* COUNT 100
1) "0"
2) 1) "source1:20240506:part1:subtype1:2"
   2) "source1:20240506:part1:subtype1:1"

Is this an accurate example of what you are running into? What version of Redis are you using?

yes that's an exact representation. I tried your example and it still doesn't work. I've got redis 6.2.6. Maybe i'll try and upgrade. Thanks for the example

I am running the latest version of Redis Stack.
